# What is the number of animals in a farm when the quantities add up?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

The problem is as follows:

> In a farm there are cows, horses and pigs. Not counting the cows there
> are $124$ animals, not counting the horses $36$ animals, not counting
> the pigs $28$ animals. Using this information, what is the number of
> horses on that farm?

The alternatives in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{16 horses}\\
2.&\textrm{18 horses}\\
3.&\textrm{12 horses}\\
4.&\textrm{8 horses}\\
5.&\textrm{16 horses}\\
\end{array}$

What I've attempted to solve this problem was to make a set of equations as follows:

Assuming cows is $c$, horses is $h$ and pigs is $p$ then:

$h+p=124$

$c+p=36$

$c+h=28$

Then adding subtracting the third from the second:

$h-p=-8$

And adding this to the first becomes into:

$2h=116$

$h=58$

Thus the number of horses would make $58$ horses but it doesn't appear in the alternatives. On a second analysis I found that:

$2h+2c+2p=188$

$h+c+p=94$

But since: $h+p=124$ this makes the earlier equation a contradiction. What could I be doing wrong?. Can somoene help me here?. What part did went not right?.

Comment: In the stated problem, cows = -30, horses = 58, pigs = 66 is the unique solution to the query as you have stated it.

Comment: Your equations are correct, but there must be a typo in the problem.  The solution is $h=58,p=66,c=-30$.  If we don't allow negative animals, the third equation shows that there are at most $28$ horses, and the second that there are at most $36$ pigs, so that gives at most $64$ animals not counting the cows, and the first equation is impossible.

Comment: @saulspatz Hopefully it seems that my analysis was not incorrect. Its a relief. It looks that it was a typo in the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s an error in the problem. If you add all three of your original equations together, you find that $2(c+h+p)=188$, which implies that there are altogether $94$ animals. However, this clearly contradicts the statement that there are $124$ animals not counting the cows.

I’ll take a guess that it was supposed to say that there are $24$ animals not counting the cows. In that case we’d have $2(c+h+p)=88$, for a total of $44$ animals, and since $36$ of them are not horses, there would be $8$ horses.

Comment: By looking in my book, you got to the right answer. It seems that there was a typo. I was confused at there could be an error in my analysis. But it looks not. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: You’re welcome.